# Reading ALOS PALSAR data using gdal

Tags: gdal

I have downloaded ALOS-1 PALSAR level 1.0 data from data archive  from Alaska Satellite Facility. After unzipping files ,I am getting image files,Leader Files,Trailer File and Volume File. All the files have extension of .0__A. I am trying to open the Image file(IMG) through gdal.Open and ReadAsArray() function but gdal is not able to open the data.

How can I visualise the data?

I am using gdal 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Recent release of GDAL has included Drivers for opening ALOS PALSAR. You can try that once. Also, you can open only VOL******.0_A files.